# Window resize and scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, resize

I am currently facing issues with scrolling event after the resize.

for example

```
$(window).on("resize scroll",detectScrollingForSectionHeaderWithHyperLink2).trigger("scroll")


function detectScrollingForSectionHeaderWithHyperLink2()
        {
            console.log("cccc")
        }
```

The script above will execute the function detectScrollingForSectionHeaderWithHyperLink2 whenever browser scroll or resize.

In my testing, upon page loaded, each time i scroll the function detectScrollingForSectionHeaderWithHyperLink2 executed well. But right after i resize my browser and scroll the mouse, the scrolling event could not be captured. I am hoping someone could shine a light upon this kinda issue.

Comment: Are you sure? Most browsers increase a number instead of printing the message again and again. `number of logs + cccc`.

Comment: Looks ok to me here http://jsfiddle.net/cup4B/

Comment: I have tested your example in Version 33.0.1750.46 beta CHROME and and jqeury 1.10, it works for me

Comment: hmm sorry guys seems like other js function that seems to have corrupt the default working code. something to do with height and overflow hidden/scroll..still investigating...